# VisualForce : page Block Section Item for Multi Select Option

Tags: visualforce

Hi I get the following error for `pageblockSectionItem`. I need to make this fields visible only for certain profiles  I have few more `selectOption` that I need to add.

> Error: `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` may have no more than 2 child components

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!IF($UserRole.Name =='User' || $UserRole.Name =='Salesforce Administrator'  , true , false)}">
  <td class="labelCol" style="border-bottom:0px;">
              <apex:outputLabel value="Expiration Date (Mo/Yr)"/>
            </td>
            <td class="data2Col" style="border-bottom:0px;">
            <apex:selectList id="sandler"  value="{!sandlerAccount}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="-- None --"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="test" itemLabel="tt"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="test2" itemLabel="tt"/>     

            </apex:selectList>

    </td>
```

Comment: You're missing your closing `"` after your second `selectOption`.

Comment: Also note that you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with `condition`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes sorry when I was typing it I forgot to put the '"' but I do that in my actual code

Comment: @AdrianLarson but I still need the PageBlockSectionItem to do the condition correct?  I only wanna show those fields on certain roles in that page

Comment: Yeah, just take everything between `IF(` and the first `,`. It's easier to read also if you switch to use `OR` instead of `||` for merge fields imo.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 1

Comment: rendered="{!IF($UserRole.Name =='user' || $UserRole.Name =='user2')}" is this how you mean it?

Comment: No, `rendered="{!OR($UserRole.Name = 'user', $UserRole.Name = 'user2')}"`.